# Android AnimationSet using XML Resource

Tags: android, android-animation

I have two animations in my anim/ folder. One is a one shot and the other loops.

I am trying to play the loop after the one shot is finished.

I tried using an AnimationSet, but I'm doing it wrong.

```
AnimationSet as = new AnimationSet(true);
Animation AnimFirst = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(null, R.anim.oneshot);
Animation AnimSecond = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(null, R.anim.loop);
as.addAnimation(AnimFirst);
as.addAnimation(AnimSecond);

ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
image1.startAnimation(as);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for an `AnimationListener` to run your second animation once the first one is finished. Something like.-

```
Animation animFirst = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(null, R.anim.oneshot);
Animation animSecond = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(null, R.anim.loop);

final ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);

animFirst.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        image1.startAnimation(animSecond);
    }
});

image1.startAnimation(animFirst);
```

This way, you don't really need an [AnimationSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html), which is supposed to play a set of animations **simultaneously**, not in a sequence.

Comment: Is there any way to get this to work inside of a button onClick?

Comment: It should work, yes. Try encapsulating the code snippet in a new function, and call it inside onclick.